# Converting Monthly Data to Daily Data on Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have data columns of the last day of each month with a value. Apparently, the value of the entire month is stationary. I have to make a new column with daily dates while having the particular month's value mentioned for every day of the month. I tried using `VLOOKUP()` but was unsuccessful.

A screenshot of the data sheet can be seen below.

[image: data sheet]

Comment: Why doesn't `vlookup` work? This is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) like this -

`=vlookup(E2,$A$2:$B$12,2,true)`

The key being the `true` -

> Range_lookup    A logical value that specifies whether you want
>   VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:
>
> If TRUE or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an
>   exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than
>   lookup_value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH(EOMONTH($D2,0),$A$2:$A$12,0))
```